# Show a div only if URL has no fragment identifier

Tags: css, html, fragment-identifier

It's hard to explain what I mean, so see this jsfiddle first: http://jsfiddle.net/Gsggy/

When a user clicks 1, div number 1 shows, same for the others, simple enough.

However, before a user has clicked on a number, there is no div there, because it relies on the # value in the URL

How can I set a default div that is there with a blank url e.g. www.jsfiddle.com but disappears when someone clicks a number and makes it www.jsfiddle.com/#1

Comment: Be aware that ids starting with a number are not allowed. Also please clarify if your default div should be one of the elements that have an id or if it should be an extra element.

Comment: That was just a mockup, my actual divs have proper names.

It should be a sibling of the divs(so a sibling of #1 #2 and #3), it can have an ID, but i dont want to have to use #default in the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is you can't really target an element in a way to tell it "do something while someone else is the target".

There are however some workarounds to this dilemma. One solution would be to always dispay the default content and display the target elements above.

You can use the fact that elements that appear later in the dom are usually rendered above nodes which appear earlier. So you could have for example a negative top margin or an absolute positioned element cover up your default content.

Improving on your html structure:

```
<div class="default" id="z">0</div>
<div id="a">1</div>
<div id="b">2</div>
<div id="c">3</div>
```

This css does work:

```
.default {
    display: block;
    background: #eff;
}

div + div {
    margin-top: -102px;
}

div:target {
    background: #eef;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

The downside to this particular approach is that you need to know the exact dimensions of your default content.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gsggy/4/

Answer (score 0):

use nth-of-type or last-of-type selector and make a default div in last  i think it will work in your case